# unable to contact ROS master at

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
This is a simple question but troubled me hours.

I am following the turtlebot3 tutorial.
Setting up the bashrc of host-pc with PC IP address 192.168.48.132 :

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://**192.168.48.132**:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=**192.168.48.132**
```

Setting up the bashrc of turtlebot3 with its own IP 192.168.137.192 :

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://**192.168.48.132**:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=**192.168.137.192**
```

Then, run the roscore on remote PC with the printout like this:

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.48.132:38089/
ros_comm version 1.12.14

SUMMARY

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2167]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.48.132:11311/

setting /run_id to ee0e1f5e-41df-11ea-8d67-000c29f89067
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2180]
started core service [/rosout]
```

then run

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch on turtlebot3
```

get **'unable to contact ROS master at [http://192.168.48.132:11311/]'**

the bashrc setting ip is the same but why the turtlebot cannot find the ros master?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342729/unable-to-contact-ros-master-at/) by [sinsinsinsin](https://answers.ros.org/users/51291/sinsinsinsin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2020-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

solved.
It is because I am using Virtual Machine.
The virtual ubuntu's ip address is 192.168.48.132 which is not the real wireless router address which starts with 192.168.137.xx

---

Originally posted by [sinsinsinsin](https://answers.ros.org/users/51291/sinsinsinsin/) with karma: 28 on 2020-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Siemen](https://answers.ros.org/users/72792/siemen/) on 2021-04-01**:
So How did you solve this problem? Can the virtual machine connect to ROSMASTER?